# What could I be doing wrong for the drawn image not to get saved in my SD Card?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the necessary permissions set in the manifest file and the Toast notification actually shows that the image is saved. Here's the method doing the save job.

```
public void saveImage () {

    int count = 0;

    File sdDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File subDirectory = new File(sdDirectory.toString() + "/Pictures/Paint");

    if (subDirectory.exists()) {

        File[] existing = subDirectory.listFiles();

        for (File file : existing) {

            if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".png")) {

                count++;

            }

        }

    } else {

        subDirectory.mkdir();

    }

    if (subDirectory.exists()) {

        File image = new File(subDirectory, "/drawing_" + (count + 1) + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;

        try {

            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);

            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {


        } catch (IOException e) {


        }

    }

}
```

My images are created from the drawn files. What could I be missing?

Comment: Where do you exactly write content to the new file?

Comment: @MrFisherman I believe this line **fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);** should be writing it. Being a long time I programmed in android and the tutorial I followed has it exactly like this.

Comment: But you just tells fileOutputStream where is output file/path, it seems like you don't write anything to this file. Check this out: https://www.iditect.com/how-to/53663305.html Also put breakpoint on if(subDirectory.exists()) line and run debbuger mode, check if it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either your `mBitmap` variable has nothing inside, or you added an extra `/` in the line where you create the image `File`. Try it like this:

```
File image = new File(subDirectory, "drawing_" + (count + 1) + ".png");
```

Either way, if that does not work, you will have to debug it. I would remove the try -> catch statement and see if you get an error, until you know it works perfectly, then only add the try -> catch back in.